# ubuntu запретить пользователю заходить в чужие папки

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

Как в ubuntu 14.04 запретить пользователю заходить в чужие домашние папки?
Если сделать:

```
#Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match User alexey
Chrootdirectory /home/alexey
ForceCommand internal-sftp
X11Forwarding no
AllowTCPForwarding no
```

то невозможно вообще даже подключиться к серверу по ssh. Google не помог.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если под «заходить» подразумевалось «просматривать содержимое», то этого можно добиться, сняв все биты доступа для «остальных» (**o**thers) у домашних каталогов пользователей.

обычно домашние каталоги пользователей располагаются в каталоге `/home`. следовательно:

```
$ sudo chmod o= /home/*
```

---

см. документацию к программе [*chmod*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod): [`$ man chmod`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#chmod-invocation)

Comment: Спасибо, уже разобрался, добавил группу на свою папку (/home/nehalem) nehalem:www-data и права 750, теперь мою папку не могут не просматривать, не входить